# What is the difference between bolded and normal properties in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

A coworker noticed in a PR where I made adjustments to some build configurations that the line

```
 <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
```

was added to one project. Below is the difference between master (right) and my branch (left). In the left, the text for windows sdk is bold, in the right its faint.

[image: branch (left) v master (right)]

As far as I recall, I never changed this, but the line got added and I don't understand why or how or what the deal with that is. The options in the dropdowns are also different.

[image: master]
[image: branch]

So,

1. What makes some properties bold and others faint?
2. Why do bold properties have the `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties for C++ files and projects can be inherited. From "[Property inheritance in Visual Studio projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/project-property-inheritance?view=msvc-170)":

> On a property page, a property in bold is defined in the current
> context. A property in normal font is inherited.

The `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` option essentially clears a value defined in the current context that is overriding the inherited value.